# How to remove duplicates in my WEB-INF/lib jar files?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, pom.xml

I know there seems to be a lot of discussion on StackOverflow about the error I am getting, but I don't see exactly the same situation and I'd like to better understand the issue I am having.

I am getting the following failed to start error "Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start"

After doing some research it seems like this is a WEB-INF/lib and/or a pom.xml dependency issue. It looks like people have been able to solve their issues by removing a variety of jar files or updating their pom file/removing a variety of certain dependencies.

When I look at my WEB-INF/lib jar files, it seems that mine are duplicating... Does any one know why I am getting double/2 versions of the same jar files, and could they tell me which dependency they are coming from in my pom.xml file? I think my project wont start on Tomcat & is getting this issue due to the duplicates, as things are already running once when it tries to start the other duplicate jar files.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.mySite</groupId>
 <artifactId>mySitePortal</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <name>mySitePortal</name>
 <description>mySitePortal</description>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.dblock.waffle</groupId>
   <artifactId>waffle-spring-security3</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security.kerberos</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-kerberos-web</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
   <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <!-- flying saucer pdf -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
   <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
   <version>9.1.4</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- jxls simple excel -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
   <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
   <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.14</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
   <artifactId>jxls-jexcel</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.metawidget.modules</groupId>
   <artifactId>metawidget-all</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
   <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
   <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

Here's a snip of my WEB-INF/lib jars, showing some duplicates.
[image]

Comment: It starts by you having conflicting versions in the pom.xml in the first place. E.g. for Spring Boot you define 2.0.6 for the parent, but you include spring-boot-starter-web with version 1.4.2. So i would start cleaning that up.

Comment: spring-context-support should also be removed. IIRC the content was moved into the other Spring libs, and with Spring Boot you should have all necessary Spring libs in there.

Comment: Thanks @dunni I removed the Spring-Context-Support and that removed most of the duplicates. The code base is using both of the Spring Parent and starter-web in different ways, so cleaning that up will take a bit more time as I have to refactor some code.

Comment: If you get "child container failed to start" that means that you should look in the other log files to find out why. Even failing to connect to a database on startup can make an application fail to start. It doesn't have to be a library issue. (You may, of course, still have a library issue.) But look at the log files: that's why they are there.